# Частота слов в тексте

Tags: php, python, bash, perl, соревнование

Ниже приведенный скрипт на Python подсчитывает частоту слов в тексте (непрерывных последовательностей букв за исключением знаков препинания) и выводит таблицу результатов.

Работает правильно. Вопрос вот в чем: можно ли сделать то же самое проще (например, меньше строк кода) на Python, Bash, PHP, Perl или это лучший способ?

```
import sys
import string

file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()

table = string.maketrans("", "")
words = text.lower().split(None)

frequencies = {}
for word in words:
    trimmed = word.translate(table, string.punctuation)
    frequencies[trimmed] = frequencies.get(trimmed, 0) + 1

keys = sorted(frequencies.keys())
for word in keys:
    print "%-32s %d" % (word, frequencies[word])
```

Comment: Это очень плохой способ. Этот скрипт упадет при попытке проанализировать хоть сколько нибудь большой текст. Другое дело, что с точки зрения простоты он вероятно один из самых простых.

Comment: Пока не падает: я запускаю на текстах до мегабайта. :)

Comment: Используйте http://www.nltk.org/ и не парьтесь :)

Comment: @yapycoder Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем примере встречая подобную строку: "aa,bb,cc" она считается как "aabbcc 1", а должно быть:
    aa 1
    bb 1
    cc 1

Итак, мой вариант на Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my %result;
while (<>) {
    $result{ lc $_ }++ for /(\w+)/g;
}

printf "%-32s %d\n", $_, $result{$_} for sort keys %result;
```

можно его конечно скомпоновать и в одну строчку. но будет нечитаемо.

Comment: Лаконично!

Comment: Замените cmp на <=> в случае с cmp будет сортировка по строкам, те:
10,2,3,4 ...

Comment: true perl code

Comment: shurik'у, я знаю, я специально так сделал, ибо так сортируется и у автора поста. Так как пример вывода он не сделал, ориентируюсь на его код. Спасибо за это напоминание, вырежу лишнее в моём коде =).

Comment: Блин, красота конечно... Хоть на перл переходи.

Comment: Перловый код можно сократить:

    #!/usr/bin/perl -wn 
    use strict;
    our %result;
    $result{ lc $_ }++ for /(\w+)/g;
    END {
        printf "%-32s %d\n", $_, $result{$_} for sort keys %result;
    }

Или даже так, до однострочника:

    perl -ne '$c{lc$_}++for/(\w+)/g;END{printf"%-32s %d\n",$_,$c{$_}for sort keys%c}'


Answer (score 3):

python, регекспы

```
import re
import sys
import operator

file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
text = file.read().decode("utf8")
file.close()

words = re.findall(r"(\w+)", text, re.UNICODE)

stats = {}
for word in words:
    stats[word] = stats.get(word, 0) + 1

stats_list = sorted(stats.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
for word, count in stats_list:
    print "%-32s %d" % (word, count)
```

Answer (score 3):

Подсчёт частоты слов с поддержкой Unicode (`.casefold()`, `\w+`):

- текст, в кодировке из локали, задаётся из файлов, указанных в командной строке, или со стандартного ввода (если не указаны)
- слова выводятся в порядке убывания популярности
- кодировка для вывода может отличаться от кодировки на входе
- выводит построчно, с указанным в вопросе форматированием (ширина под слово — 32 символа)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import re
from collections import Counter

words = (word for line in fileinput.input()
         for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line.casefold()))
for word, count in Counter(words).most_common():
    print("%-32s %d" % (word, count))
```

Вот версия, близкая к поведению Питон 2 кода из вопроса:

- читает байты из файла, переводит их в нижний регистр, разбивает на слова по стандартному пробелу (не поддерживает Unicode)
- удаляет ascii пунктуацию из каждого слова (может пустая строка остаться)
- считает получившиеся слова, сортирует их по величине байт
- выводит построчно, с указанным в вопросе форматированием (ширина под слово — 32 байта)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import string
import sys
from collections import Counter
from pathlib import Path

words = Path(sys.argv[1]).read_bytes().lower().split()
chars_to_trim = string.punctuation.encode()
trimmed = (word.translate(None, chars_to_trim) for word in words)
for word, count in sorted(Counter(trimmed).items()):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"%-32s %d%s" % (word, count, os.linesep.encode()))
```

Два примера разный вывод генерируют как правило.

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my %frec;

sub calc{
    $frec{ $1 }++ while( $_[0] =~ /\b(\S+)\b/g );
}

my $fileName = shift or die( "Uasge: $0 filenameWithText" );
open FF, $fileName;
calc( $_ ) for( <FF> );
foreach( sort{ $frec{$b} <=> $frec{$a} } keys %frec ){
    printf( "%-32s %d\n", $_, $frec{ $_ } );
}
close FF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Скрипт на bash/awk, для коллекции:

```
#/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` filename"
  exit 1
fi

for x in $(sed -rn 's/\W+/ /gp' $1);
do
  echo $x
done | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sort | awk '
{
  if (!word) {
    word = $1
    num = 0
  } else if (word == $1) {
    num++
  } else {
    print word, num+1
    word = $1
    num = 0
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/), который предназначен для работы с естественными текстами:

```
In [54]: from nltk import word_tokenize, FreqDist

In [55]: data = open(r'c:/temp/TWAIN.LOG').read()

In [56]: fdist = FreqDist(word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(data) if word.isalpha())
```

10 наиболее часто встречающихся слов:

```
In [57]: fdist.most_common(10)
Out[57]:
[('message', 10),
 ('ctwtrace', 4),
 ('ctwunk', 3),
 ('dsm', 3),
 ('dsmentrydiagexit', 3),
 ('rc', 3),
 ('cc', 3),
 ('thunker', 2),
 ('scannerredirection', 2),
 ('to', 2)]
```

весь словарь целиком:

```
In [58]: dict(fdist)
Out[58]:
{'message': 10,
 'ctwunk': 3,
 'reset': 1,
 'log': 1,
 'starting': 1,
 'thunker': 2,
 'why': 1,
 'ca': 1,
 'we': 1,
 'find': 1,
 'the': 1,
 'window': 1,
 'dsm': 3,
 'dsmentrydiagexit': 3,
 'rc': 3,
 'cc': 3,
 'ctwtrace': 4,
 'scannerredirection': 2,
 'to': 2,
 'null': 2,
 'control': 2,
 'identity': 2,
 'getfirst': 1,
 'getnext': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Мой скромный вариант:

```
import sys, string

text = sorted(open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read().translate(string.maketrans('', ''), string.punctuation).split())

for i in range(len(text) - 1):
    if text[i + 1] == text[i]: continue
    print '%s %d' % (text[i], text.count(text[i]))
```

для python3:

```
import sys, string

text = sorted(open(sys.argv[1]).read().lower().translate(''.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split())
for i in range(len(text) - 1):
    if text[i + 1] == text[i]: continue
    print('{0:>20} {1:<}'.format((text[i]), text.count(text[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Php вариант частоты вхождений слов в тексте:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[\s\.\,\!]+/", " ", $text);
$text = explode(" ", $text);
foreach (array_count_values($text) as $key => $value)
{
     echo '<br>'.$key.'-->'.$value;
}
```

Comment: Там, еще, у автора сортиоровка.

Comment: PHPсты, такие PHPсты... =)

1. У автора полноценная программа, соответственно он подразумевает увидеть полноценные программы
2. данные приводятся к нижнему регистру
3. данные сортируются
4. программы консольные и вывод не в браузер
5. вывод форматируется по ширине столбцов и имеет другой вид
6. данный кусок считает словами - "=", "№4" и множество других сочетаний символов

P.S. не надо писать код для того чтобы писать код, надо писать код который даёт требуемый функционал