# Как выделить ключевые понятия из множества описаний на естественном языке?

Tags: python, парсер, nlp, естественный-язык

Добрый день.

Подскажите, какие подходы и библиотеки(python) можно использовать для решения такой задачи:

Есть множество спарсеных описаний вакансий. Для каждой вакансии я могу выделить блок с требованиями к соискателям на эту вакансию. Получается по 5-15 строк примерно такого вида:

> - уверенное знание Python;
> - знакомство с Django, Tornado, Twisted;
> - понимание и умение применять паттерны проектирования;
> - опыт настройки, оптизимации и работы с MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB;
> - умение работать не только с ORM, но и с “голым” SQL;
> - опыт разработки высоконагруженных проектов;
> - любовь к тестированию кода;
> - неистовое желание постоянно учиться новому и познавать;
> - опыт работы от 2 лет;
> - чтение документации и литературы на английском языке;
> - коммуникабельность, ответственность, умение работать в команде.

Хочется проанализировать весь этот массив вакансий и получить:

1. Представление о том, какие знания, навыки, технологии наиболее востребованы
2. Какие из них наиболее часто встречаются вместе. Например, Tornado и Twisted часто встречаются в одной строчке. Какие-то слова могут встречаться часто в пределах одной вакансии, но в разных строчках.

Пока единственный подход, который мне приходит в голову - разбить всё на отдельные слова и как-то анализировать, как часто встречаются отдельные слова и их сочетания.

Как именно оценить общую частоту встречаемости, чтобы учитывалось, насколько близко или далеко в тексте расположены слова?

Какие ещё есть подходы?

Как мне решить следующие проблемы:

1. Отфильтровать союзы, предлоги и общие слова. Почти в каждой вакансии встречаются слова "понимание" чего-то, "опыт" чего-то, "умение" делать что-то. В итоге у таких слов высокая частота встречаемости, но ценности для анализа они не представляют.
2. Учитывать, что одно и то же понятие может быть выражено разными словами. Например "тестирование", "написание тестов", "юнит-тесты", "unit testing"

Comment: Вам нужен искусственный интеллект. Если вы выполните ваше задание, можете подаваться в Гугл.

Comment: @VladD - я думаю в таком случае это Гугл будет подаваться Александру.

Comment: Векторизируйте свой корпус, ищите косинус угла между векторами - это близость. См. td/idf, bag of words, разберите, как работает word2vec. Если частотные методы (даже самые изощренные) вас не устроят по качеству, то это вилы и можно на годы зависнуть

Answer (score 1):

Когда я только учился кодить на пайтон, я написал такой скрипт для поиска наиболее встречаемых слов в текстовом файле:

```
import re

normal_dict = {} # normal dictionary


def readfilelines(filename, dictionary):
    with open (filename, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            result = re.findall(r'(\b[a-z]+\b)', line, re.IGNORECASE)

            for word in result:
                if word in dictionary.keys():
                    cur_value = dictionary[word] + 1
                    dictionary[word] = cur_value
                else:
                    dictionary[word] = 1


def writefile(filename, dictionary):
    with open (filename, "w") as file:
        for k, v in dictionary:
            s = str(k) + " - " + str(v) + "\n"
            file.write(s)


def sort_dictionary_by_value(dictionary):
    sorted_dict = [(k, dictionary[k]) for k in sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)]
    return sorted_dict


readfilelines("input.txt", normal_dict)
sorted_dict = sort_dictionary_by_value(normal_dict)
writefile("output.txt", sorted_dict)
```

На вход вы подаёте текстовый файл, на выходе получаете файл с градацией встречаемости слов от большего к меньшему в таком формате:

> Слово - N (где N - сколько раз это слово встретилось)

P.S. Каждое слово будет расположено на новой строке

Думаю, можно попробовать изменить регулярку с `\w+` на `[a-z]+, re.IGNORECASE`, чтобы поискать именно фреймворки и технологии, потому что они, обычно, названы латинскими буквами (кроме 1С, хотя может и она латиницей написана).

В любом случае, как вариант записать все требования в один файл, а потом к нему применить этот скрипт с изменённой регуляркой, и в файле с выходом будут фреймворки и технологии от самых популярных до самых невостребованных.

Для теста я скопировал описание нескольких вакансий в файл и прогнал их с помощью скрипта и регулярки `r'\b[a-z]+\b', re.IGNORECASE`

Вот [ссылка](http://dropmefiles.com/rxymT) на входные и выходные данные

Comment: Недавно приятель, шарясь по Яндекс.Маркету заметил, что "Cвязной" причислен в фильтре к латинской C. А Haxe, к примеру, прекрасно пишется кириллицей. Так что я б не стал рассчитывать, что человеческого фактора не будет. Точно будет.

Comment: @D-side ну тут вы правы, конечно. К тому же, объявления пишет отдел HR, что потенциально делает такую сортировку ещё менее точной. В любом случае, можно подогнать нужную регулярку, либо просплитить текст и искать вхождение в списке из вариантов

Comment: Частоту слов в файле можно [проще посчитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718506/23044)