# Почему код для определения частоты слов в тексте считает бесконечно?

Tags: python

Почему код продолжается бесконечно и не заканчивается? Уже и ставила return, но тогда просчитывает только первое слово и всё.

Код:

```
def lol():
    import re #вызов регулярных выражени
    frequency = {} #задаем словарь частот {}-обозначение словаря
    with open(filename) as slova:
        text = slova.read()
        sentence_text = text.lower()
        pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{1,20}\b', sentence_text) #составляем регулярку через функция findall (вызов + граница + слова + длина мин и макс + граница, переменная)
        for word in pattern:
            count = frequency.get(word,0) #задаем ключ
            frequency[word] = count + 1
            frequency_list = frequency.keys()
            for words in frequency_list:
                print (words)
                return (frequency[words])
print (lol())
```

Comment: Ничего не бесконечно, проверьте на файле с маленьким числом слов (4-5 слов в файле например)

Comment: вы уверены, что в реальном коде отступ у второго цикла как показан в вопросе? (второй цикл должен выполняться *после* первого, а не *внутри* первого цикла)

Comment: Кстати, имена вводят в заблуждение у вас. Можно заменить: slova -> file, sentence_text -> text, pattern -> words. frequency_list не нужен. См. [Частота слов в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718506/23044)

Comment: Подскажите версию? Или вы обе попробовали?

Answer (score 4):

Как уже объяснил @Эникейщик, вложенный цикл не нужен и только замедляет выполнение (сложность алгоритма из-за вложенного цикла - `O(n^2)`). Кроме того `return` внутри него ломает код.

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/), который предназначен для работы с естественными текстами:

```
In [54]: from nltk import word_tokenize, FreqDist

In [55]: data = open(r'c:/temp/TWAIN.LOG').read()

In [56]: fdist = FreqDist(word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(data) if word.isalpha())
```

10 наиболее часто встречающихся слов:

```
In [57]: fdist.most_common(10)
Out[57]:
[('message', 10),
 ('ctwtrace', 4),
 ('ctwunk', 3),
 ('dsm', 3),
 ('dsmentrydiagexit', 3),
 ('rc', 3),
 ('cc', 3),
 ('thunker', 2),
 ('scannerredirection', 2),
 ('to', 2)]
```

весь словарь целиком:

```
In [58]: dict(fdist)
Out[58]:
{'message': 10,
 'ctwunk': 3,
 'reset': 1,
 'log': 1,
 'starting': 1,
 'thunker': 2,
 'why': 1,
 'ca': 1,
 'we': 1,
 'find': 1,
 'the': 1,
 'window': 1,
 'dsm': 3,
 'dsmentrydiagexit': 3,
 'rc': 3,
 'cc': 3,
 'ctwtrace': 4,
 'scannerredirection': 2,
 'to': 2,
 'null': 2,
 'control': 2,
 'identity': 2,
 'getfirst': 1,
 'getnext': 1}
```

Comment: ваш ответ не объясняет "почему код считается бесконечно". Есть вопрос, где ваш ответ бы подошёл: [Частота слов в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/9096/23044)

Answer (score 3):

У вас один цикл (назначение которого мне, честно говоря, не очень понятно) вложен в другой, что а) ненужно, б) приводит к повторению одной и той же ненужной работы. И чем длиннее текст, тем больше этой ненужной работы.

После первого цикла вам нужно просто вывести нужную информацию без всяких циклов:

```
    for word in pattern:
        count = frequency.get(word,0) #задаем ключ
        frequency[word] = count + 1
        frequency_list = frequency.keys()

    print frequency # слова и их частота
    print frequency_list # список встречающихся слов
```

`print (lol())` - не надо. Достаточно `lol()`, т.к. вывод текста у вас происходит в самой функции.

Comment: можно упомянуть, что ненужный вложенный цикл делает алгоритм квадратичным `O(n**2)` Если число слов в файле на порядок увеличить, то в сто раз дольше работать будет. Для миллиона слов попытается 10**12 раз `print` вызвать. Связанный вопрос (ещё пример квадратичного алгоритма и анекдот): [Непонятное замедление конкатенации в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710117/23044)